# How can I cover $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a vector space over itself with hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $V=\mathbb{Z}_5$ a vector space over itself, How can I write $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a union of finite hyperplanes? I am just looking for an example of I can do it because people told me that the case of my field is finite is trivial, but still don't know the process to conclude that. Thanks.

Comment: $V=\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a vector space over itself is one-dimensional. A hyperplane, being codimension $1$, is just a point. Since there are finitely many (5) points, you have a finite cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyperplanes defined by
$$
x = 0\\
x = 1\\
x = 2\\
x = 3\\
x = 4
$$
cover $\Bbb Z / 5 \Bbb Z$, assuming that's what you mean by $\Bbb Z_5$.